# Adding Provider to SSMS for Linked Server Object

Tags: sql-server, db2, odbc, ssms

How do I add a provider to the drop down list pictured below? I have successful connected a DB2 server to this server but queries are slow since it is using OLE DB. Is it possible to add ODBC to this list? If so how/where do I edit the list?

[image: ProviderDropDown]

Comment: You have to install the provider drivers on the host machine.

Comment: https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-configure-a-linked-server-using-the-odbc-driver/

Comment: Linked server use OLE DB, although you can use ODBC via the Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers. That will add an extra layer and may not address your performance issue.